# Return self (rather than nil) from Hash#[] when key doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, hash

Typically when an element is passed into a hash with no matching key, the hash returns `nil`.

```
hsh = {1 => "one", 2 => "two"}
hsh[3] #=> nil
```

I want to form a hash that returns the value passed into it if there is no match.

```
hsh[3] #=> 3
```

I'm guessing that a solution for this might involve a lambda of some kind...?

** Right now I'm using a clumsy solution for this that uses a conditional method to prevent non-matching keys from being passed into the hash..

Comment: Do you want to modify the Hash class itself or are you open to other methods of fetching?

Comment: so long as the solution is brief in code I'm open to that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to return new values but not add them:

```
 h = Hash.new { |_hash, key| key }
```

To initially populate this hash, you could do:

```
 h.merge( {1 => "one", 2 => "two"} )
```

If the hash is already created*:

```
 h.default_­proc = proc do |_hash,key|
     key
 end

#h[3]
#=> 3
```

**only in ruby 1.9 and above*

Comment: why can't a lambda be used for this?

Comment: @boulder_ruby why do you want to use a `lambda`? The proposed solution is simpler. Internally, the `Hash.new` probably does something like a `proc` or `lambda` without you having to explicitly create a mechanism.

Comment: A `lambda` is mostly a `proc`, so you can use it there too.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, if the hash is already created (say it's called `old_hash`, you would create the new hash as above, then do `h.merge(old_hash)`.

Comment: It's more than just good practice. Unused local variables trigger a warning unless they start with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
hsh.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = key
end
```

To return the key only, it's a trivial change:

```
hsh.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
  key
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if OP wants to _add_ that key, just return it.

Comment: Does this work? I tried it (both examples) and neither of them do what the OP's asking.

Comment: But from that link: " It is not possible to set the default to a Proc that will be executed on each key lookup."